# Using RxJS version 5 with ionic 4

Tags: rxjs, ionic4

I am migrating my ionic 3 app to ionic 4 . I have read the migration guide in which it is mentioned that with ionic 4 , RxJS 6 has came . 
Is it mandatory to use RxJS 6 ? Can I still use RxJS 5 with ionic 4 . If yes , how ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if some mad scientist has come up with a way, but the v5 to 6 for rxjs was a big change, so I doubt it.

You can check out the official migration guide:

- https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Seems you will have to upgrade your code for this at the same time.